# Best practice to organize extension methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, extension-methods

I have a bunch of extension methods of String and other JavaScript types, they now reside in global namespace.
What is the best practice to organize those extension methods? Should I encapsulate them inside a namespace? If yes, how to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Just curious. How do you going to use namespace if you extend String's prototype?

Comment: I think if it is a method that would belong to the String class, you declare it there. (< full stop || fool's stop - u decide). If it is anything else you namespace it. The question is "Should I encap.... namespace", well no! if they belong to a build-in type (logically)

Answer (score 2):

[**Namespace your JavaScript if you need to refer to it elsewhere.**](https://github.com/stevekwan/best-practices/blob/master/javascript/best-practices.md#namespace-your-javascript-if-you-need-to-refer-to-it-elsewhere)

```
  // define your global namespace
  var Extensions = Extensions || {};

  // add modules to it
  Extensions.String = function() {
    var myPrivateProperty = 2;
    var myPublicProperty = 1;

    var myPrivateFunction = function() {
      console.log("myPrivateFunction()");
    };

    var myPublicExtension = function() {
      // this extension is being called, now what?
      console.log("myPublicExtension()");
    };

    // this object will be returned, giving access to public vars/methods
    return {
      myPublicProperty: myPublicProperty,
      myPublicExtension : myPublicExtension
    };
  }();

  console.log("Calling myPublicExtension()...");
  Extensions.String.myPublicExtension();
```

[**Anonymously scope JavaScript if you’re never going to call it elsewhere.**](https://github.com/stevekwan/best-practices/blob/master/javascript/best-practices.md#anonymously-scope-javascript-if-youre-never-going-to-call-it-elsewhere)

```
// This will keep your namespace clean
(function() {
    // here you can define your modules, functions, etc..

    var x = 123;
    console.log(x);

    // to make something global you can define it like
    window.globalVar = 5;
}());
```

**Or you can extend the native javascript objects with [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) like this:**

```
String.prototype.myExtension = function(p1, p2) {
    // here is your function
    return this + p1 + p2;
}
```

This way you don't need to define namespaces and you can call your extensions directly from any object you extended:

```
var otherString = "mystring".myExtension(" is", " great!");
console.log(otherString);// mystring is cool
```

you can do that with any object in javascript

**EDIT:**

Prototype extensions don't pollute global namespace, because they are accesible only through the object you extended.

If you have many extensions consider taking them into a file like extensions.js, then add it to your pages whenever you need those extensions. This way extensions.js can be cached by the browser and will be loaded faster

Comment: I am using prototype to extend methods, lets say I have many extension methods using that way, how to organize them? Just leave them in global namespace? Will that pollute the global namespace?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing that:

1. Encapsulating in a namespace (I think the bare minimum to keep things tidy). A custom namespace ie:

   ```
   window.MyNameSpace.trim = function(str) {
       return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
   }
   ```

   (replace MyNameSpace with a single letter! R for Raphael, L for Leaflet, etc)
2. Extend prototypes! Lots of people will disagree with that but I see no harm if it is your site and you don't override/conflict with anyone else code:

   ```
   String.prototype.trim = function () {
       return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
   };
   ```

   I find this "cleaner" since you don't pass unnecessary arguments around... but again, it is a matter of opinion... This will work for any build-in type. The rest I think should follow #1

DISCLAIMER: Code from [This](https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/extending-javascripts-string-object/) post

Comment: Care to elaborate on the -1? (maybe one of these ppl to disagree :) )

Comment: hurts the first time... but i won't try to up-vote. @codewarrior... I leave this to u cause we we have wars over your code :)))

Comment: I am using the 2nd way, extend using prototype, lets say I have many extension methods using that way, how to organize them? Just leave them in global namespace? Will that pollute the global namespace?

Comment: @codewarrior How many is many? If there are common functions like "trim" I would leave them in the namespace. However, if a group of them relates you could make it a single object/prototype into the main namespace. For example if you have "shuffle", "randomize", "removeDigits", etc which are not so commonly used methods of a String you could do: ```String.prototype.myExtension.randomize()```. It depends on the context...